# Call method of subclass from parent reference

Tags: java, osgi, aem

I have 3 OSGi bundles in such as way, implemented class is of same name but in different bundles :

```
Bundle A (com.adobe) ---- Interface ( foo() )
Bundle B (org.custom) ---- ChildClassA ( foo() {} )
Bundle C (myprj.adobe) ---- ChildClassA ( foo() {} )
```

I have a snippet as below :

```
Interface refObj;
refObj.foo();
```

How can i inject the object of specific implemented class from another bundle.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have different services that implement the same interface then you can [add properties to the services](http://blog.vogella.com/2016/09/26/configuring-osgi-declarative-services/).

On the client side you can use a reference with a target.

`@Reference(target="(key=value)")`

This reference will only match a service with a property "key" that has the value "value".